# Удаление и получение user из бд с помощью php

Tags: php, html, mysql

В БД `'secret_users'` с полями: `id`, `name`, `email`, `password`,  `ip_reg`, `data_reg` есть users.

Необходимо удалить `user c id = 15`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_fetch_array() in D:\sites\mysite.local\www\rus\index.php:84
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   D:\sites\mysite.local\www\rus\index.php on line 84

п. 84

```
 while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------



<?php
//Получаем данные
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT `ID`, `name` FROM `secret_users`');
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $result['ID'].") ".$result['Name']." - <a href='?del=".$result['ID']."'>Удалить</a><br>";
}
?>
// перед выводом  проверяем, не была ли передана переменная на их удаление, и если была, то удаляем:

<?php
//Удаляем, если что
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE `ID` = "15"'.$_GET['del'].'"');
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Пользователь удален.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $result['ID'].") ".$result['name']." - <a href='?del=".$result['ID']."'>Удалить</a><br>";
}
?>
```

код полностью:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Админ-панель</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php


    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'mysite');

   $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) exit('Ошибка соединения с БД');
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');



/*$mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `secret_users`
  (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `balance`, `ip_reg`, `data_reg`) 
  VALUES (NULL, 'Dinn', 'dinn@mail.ru', MD5('123'), '0.00', INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");


 $mysqli->close();*/


//Если переменная reg передана
   if (isset($_POST["reg"]))
    {
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
    $ip_reg = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $query = ("INSERT INTO `secret_users`
      (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`,  `ip_reg`, `data_reg`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', MD5('$password'), '$ip_reg', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if (isset($result))
        {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
        }
    }

?>


<table>
<form name='reg' action='index.php' method='post'>
    <p>
        Имя: <input type='text' name='name' />
    </p>
    <p>
        E-mail: <input type='text' name='email' />
    </p>
    <p>
        Пароль: <input type='password' name='password' />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type='submit' name='reg' value='Зарегистрироваться' />
    </p>
</table>


<?php


//Удаляем, если что
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE `ID` = "15"'.$_GET['del'].'"');
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Пользователь удален.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $result['ID'].") ".$result['name']." - <a href='?del=".$result['ID']."'>Удалить</a><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите удалить пользователя с id 15 и тем id что пришел в GET то тогда так.

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE ID IN('15','".$_GET['del']."')";
```

Если только того что пришел в GET то так

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE ID IN('".$_GET['del']."')";
```

Comment: не удаляет так, что-то с синтаксисом ';' в конце строки 
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  //$sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE `ID` = "15"'.$_GET['del'].'"');
  //$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE ID IN('15','".$_GET['del']."');
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `secret_users` WHERE ID IN('".$_GET['del']."')";
   /* if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Пользователь удален.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }*/
}


?>